# Why does Serilog define its own ILogger?

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, serilog, ilogger

I want to extend my logging code to log to my database. It appears the accepted way to do this is using Serilog and `Serilog.Sinks.MsSqlServer`. So I've installed these packages.

My understanding is that Serilog implements the existing `ILogger` interface. However, it appears that Serilog also defines an `ILogger` interface.

Having two `ILoggers` is giving me errors. And if I disable Microsoft's `ILogger`, then I get errors that `ILogger` does not accept type arguments. For example, the following won't compile:

```
public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
{
    // ...
}
```

Again, I thought Serilog simply implements the `ILogger` interface. I can't understand why this is giving me so much trouble.

Comment: `Serilog` implements `Ilogger`. But the generic `Ilogger<>` doesn't implement

Comment: What kind of `usings` do you have in your class where you get this error? (and or what global usings are you using - are either of these logging namespaces included in global usings?)

Comment: @topsail: The implicit usings that reference the libraries that include Microsoft's ILogger was implemented for me when I created the project. That's out of the box. And then I just added a using statement for Serilog in my program.cs.

Comment: AND - you never learned how to actually use the using statement except slapping it just to the top of a page, or how to reference a class without a using statement?

Comment: TL;DR Serilog predates `ILogger<T>` - the specifics of how DI maps ILogger<T> to ILogger lives in specific packages that do the wireup for that

Answer (score 1):

> Having two ILoggers is giving me errors

Nope, you defining bad includes are the source of the error. Same interface names are totally ok unless you blindly are using using statements.

> And if I disable Microsoft's ILogger, then I get errors that ILogger does not
> accept type arguments

Yes, different interfaces. You know you can prefix the namespace on the class definition, or rename classes in using?

> I thought Serilog simply implements the ILogger interface.

Given that they have very different additional functionality, why would they do that? There is a reason they offer their own interface.

THAT SAID:

If you are ok using the MS ILogger, why do you make the Serilog one available everywhere? THAT is the cause of the issue. If you are totally ok with only the microsoft implementation, there is no reason to have a reference to the serilog implementation everywhere.

Comment: Well, I need to add a using statement for Serilog if I'm going to configure it. And to prevent the duplicate symbol errors, I need to disable implicit usings. And that breaks every page that uses the Microsoft ILogger. How is that blindly adding using statements?

Comment: Remove Serilog from your implicit usings if you are. You only need it during your `IHost` configuration or wherever you are setting up dependency injection. If you **need** both usings in your configuration then create a using alias or use explicit namespaces.

Comment: " I need to add a using statement for Serilog if I'm going to configure it." - nope. Using is semantic sugar for writing out the namespace in front of the use. You can always use all or part of the namespace where you need to refer to the class name, in example when you have the same interface name in different namespaces. Heck, you can even ALIAS the name by which you refer to a specific class. There is NO "need" to use using.

Comment: @Hank: No, it's Microsoft's logger that is implemented (by the template) as implicit usings. And when I remove that, then all my pages that use ILogger are now broken.

Answer (score 1):

I can try to answer you from the comparison point of view.

ILogger from MS and ILogger from Serilog are similar but not compatible in every regard. Specifically the properties (key/value) collection.

If you are making libraries, use Microsoft's ILogger.

For apps, inject Microsoft's ILogger into libraries and frameworks if you want to make use of the functionality that comes with that, like logging requests in a web app, for instance.

For apps, use Serilog.ILogger for your own logging because it has a nicer interface and extension methods (eg, from Serilog.Timings).

I hope my explanation is making sense for your context.

Comment: This seems confusing. If my libraries use Microsoft's ILogger, and my app uses Serilog's ILogger, then if my app uses my library, how would they be compatible. Also, I still don't understand why Serilog's ILogger doesn't accept type arguments. I thought that was a key feature of ILogger.

Comment: And Serilog ILogger is not Microsoft ILogger. They are free to do what they want. The WHY is trivially simple: BECAUSE THAT IS HOW THEY PROGRAMMED IT.